# Unable to install pod 'FBSDKLoginKit' Completely It just stop there

Tags: ios, cocoapods, facebook-login

[image: FBlogin pods install unable to complete Please see this image]

The pods are taking forever to install. They just stop there. I tried it for 30mins and also tried to make it work on dummy project but still the install was not successful. My podfile looks like this.

```
 # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Benefit' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Benefit

  pod 'Spring', :git => 'https://github.com/MengTo/Spring.git'
  pod 'ImageSlideshow', '~> 1.4'
  pod 'MIBadgeButton-Swift', :git => 'https://github.com/mustafaibrahim989/MIBadgeButton-Swift.git', :branch => 'master'
  pod 'Charts'
  pod 'SideMenu'
  pod 'JTHamburgerButton', '~> 1.0'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'Google/SignIn'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'


end
```

Terminal output

```
    Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using Alamofire (4.6.0)
Installing Bolts (1.9.0)
Using Charts (3.0.4)
Installing FBSDKCoreKit (4.29.0)
Installing FBSDKLoginKit (4.29.0)

 -
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I kept the terminal as it was and after an hour It was done with installing, I think there was a problem on server side of pods.

Answer (score 0):

Just check your internet connection. And speed up Your net connection.

Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the internet connection is good, the problem was at server's end.